# How to write promise in JS to return data only if ajax req is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return a list when its updated by Jax call but its not working .

```
class ep_List {

  constructor() {
    this.urlForAjax = '';
    this.dataList = [];
    this.dataJson = '';
    this.dataParams = {};
    this.cardList = [];
  }

  getData(method, params, url) {
    this.urlForAjax = url;
    this.dataParams = params;

    if (method == 'get')
      this.callGetAjax();
    else
      this.callPostAjax();
  }

  callPostAjax() {
    $.post(this.urlForAjax, this.dataParams, this.setList.bind(this));
  }

  callGetAjax() {
    $.get(this.urlForAjax, this.setList.bind(this));
  }

  setList(res) {
    this.dataList = res;
    ajaxPromise = true;
  }

  getCardList() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      return this.cardList = createCardList(that.dataList);
    }, 3000);
  }

}
```

so right now in my `getCardList` function I have added `setTimeout` that is because if I tried to do without timeOut some thing like this

```
var listObj = new ep_List();
listObj.getData('get', '', url);
listObj.getCardList();
console.log(listObj.cardList);
```

I was getting empty list ;

I am new to OOPS in js , would be great if you guys could help

Thanks

Comment: [Promises (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [Using promises (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), [Promises (SO Documentation)](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises)

Comment: do you want to return a promise?

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa no actually , I want to remove that timeOut and return the data only when its updated by the ajax  call

Comment: ok, why dont you make just a function to do this?

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa the thing is , i am not getting a  way , like how to get the dataList value after its updated in ajax call from the classObject

Comment: you need a callback or a promise, im writing something wait

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa   I have refactored the code into two different class , you will get the idea what I am trying to do , https://jsfiddle.net/2s2p4qnc/

Answer (score 0):

This my approach using a function:

```
function getData(method, params, url) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    if(method == 'get') {
      $.get(url, params, function(res){
        resolve(res);
      });
    }
    else {
      $.post(url, function(res) {
        resolve(res);
      });
    }
  });

}

//You call this like this

getData('post', 'the_url', { the: 'params' }).then(function(res){
  //Use the response on something.
  console.log(res);
});
```

If you need a class to do this, the class still need to use a promise or a callback

Comment: You don't need `new Promise(...)`. Just return the result of `$.get(...)` or `$.post(...)`: _"As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR," returned by $.get() **implements the Promise interface**, ..."_

Comment: Thats even better, i was not sure if jquery uses promises

Comment: @Andreas and https://jsfiddle.net/2s2p4qnc/ can you look into this fiddle , see the ep_list class  I am using in multiple other class to fetch the ajax  details .